# Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

Im trying to access WOWZA Streaming Cloud through their REST API from an ASP.NET site, however have little experience in RESTSharp.

Here is an example curl I'm trying to create:

```
curl -H 'wsc-api-key: KEY' -H 'wsc-access-key: KEY' -H 'Content-Type:
application/json' -X POST -d '{"live_stream": {"name": "MyNewLiveStream",
"transcoder_type": "transcoded", "billing_mode": "pay_as_you_go",
"broadcast_location": "us_west_california", "encoder": "other_rtmp",
"delivery_method": "push", "aspect_ratio_width": 1920,
"aspect_ratio_height": 1080}}'https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1/live_streams/
```

see: https://sandbox.cloud.wowza.com/apidocs/v1/

Here is the c# code im using:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.cloud.wowza.com/");
        var newRequest = new RestRequest("api/v1/live_streams",Method.POST);
        newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-api-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAPIKey"]);
        newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-access-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAccessKey"]);
        newRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var body = "{\"live_stream\": {" +
            "\"aspect_ratio_height\": 720," +
            "\"aspect_ratio_width\": 1280," +
            "\"billing_mode\": \"pay_as_you_go\"," +
            "\"broadcast_location\": \"us_west_california\"," +
            "\"closed_caption_type\": \"none\"," +
            "\"delivery_method\": \"push\"," +
            "\"encoder\": \"wowza_gocoder\"," +
            "\"hosted_page\": true," +
            "\"hosted_page_sharing_icons\": true," +
            "\"name\": \"MyLiveStream\"," +
            "\"player_countdown\": false," +
            "\"player_responsive\": true," +
            "\"player_type\": \"original_html5\"," +
            "\"player_width\": 0," +
            "\"recording\": false," +
            "\"target_delivery_protocol\": \"hls\"," +
            "\"transcoder_type\": \"transcoded\"," +
            "\"use_stream_source\": false}";

        newRequest.AddJsonBody(body);
        IRestResponse myResponse = client.Execute(newRequest);
```

Following modifications based on the responses, the response code is now

> "{\"meta\":{\"status\":401,\"code\":\"ERR-401-InvalidApiKey\",\"title\":\"Invalid Api Key Error\",\"message\":\"Invalid API key.\",\"description\":\"\",\"links\":[]}}"

Comment: Try `newRequest.AddParameter("content-type", "application/json");
newRequest.AddParameter("wsc-api-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAPIKey"]);`
`

Comment: When you modify your question, try not to remove the error message and statements you had previously - add more details as an update instead. Otherwise someone looking at the question later will find the responses irrelevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headers are wrong- you dont need to repeat content-type in value and remove `:` from the api-key name:

```
 newRequest.AddParameter("content-type", "application/json"); 
 newRequest.AddParameter("wsc-api-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAPIKey"]);
```

**Update as OP updated the question**

So now after the modification, the call is through and is working fine. The current error is regarding invalid api key you are passing - may be the access key/api key you are passing is invlaid/expired.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to add "content-type", "wsc-api-key" and "wsc-access-key" as request parameters?

They should be added in the request header as following.

```
   newRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "Content-Type: application/json");
   newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-api-key:", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAPIKey"]);
   newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-access-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAccessKey"]);
```

Comment: Any reason, this was unmarked as answer and reputation removed?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help - i can now interact seamlessly with Wowza Cloud Streaming through the REST api wrapped by C# and using restsharp.
The solution in the end was to use the visual studio function to generate template JSON classes through Paste Special (see [In C#, how do I model a JSON object with multiple nested arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253256/in-c-how-do-i-model-a-json-object-with-multiple-nested-arrays)) - generating the WowzaLivestream class.

Then using this code in the end:

```
_restClient = new RestClient("https://api-sandbox.cloud.wowza.com");
var newRequest = new RestRequest("api/v1/live_streams", Method.POST);
newRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-api-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAPIKey"]);
        newRequest.AddHeader("wsc-access-key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WowzaAccessKey"]);
        newRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        newRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        var requestBody = new WowzaLivestream
        {
            live_stream = new Live_Stream
            {
                aspect_ratio_height = 1024,
                aspect_ratio_width = 1900,
                billing_mode = "pay_as_you_go",
                broadcast_location = "eu_ireland",
                closed_caption_type = "none",
                delivery_method = "push",
                encoder = "other_rtmp",
                name = "WowzaLStest2: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                player_countdown = true,
                player_responsive = true,
                player_type = "original_html5",
                player_width = 0,
                recording = false,
                target_delivery_protocol = "hls",
                transcoder_type = "transcoded",
                use_stream_source = false
            }
        };

        var json = newRequest.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody);
        newRequest.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse myResponse = _restClient.Execute(newRequest);
```

It turns out that the URL used was wrong - it isnt specifically stated in the documentation but for sandbox use, the URL is https://api-sandbox.cloud.wowza.com.